# Vue - detect component inside slot

Tags: vue.js, components

I have this slot inside my tile component. I basically need to detect a specific other component which is supposed to be used inside this slot BUT the slot also supports other html tags not just this specific component. Is there a way  to detect a special component e.g. `<listitem />` inside the slot?

```
<div class="tile">
  <template v-if="$slots['headline']">
    <slot name="headline" />
  </template>
</div>
```

**Edit**
The basic idea is the following

```
<tile>
  <template #headline>
    <listitem />
  </template>
</tile>

<tile>
  <template #headline>
    <h1>Some headline</h1>
  </template>
</tile>
```

I have those two options on how you can utelise this header slot. If there is a just a normal html tag e.g. `<h1>`, I would like to apply the corresponding css styles. If there is the `<listitem />` component I need to apply other styles

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As content of the slot is passed to the component as an array of [VNode's](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/vnode.js) accessible via [this.$slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-slots) (in case of scoped-slots it is function returning array of VNode's) you can write a function like this:

```js
methods: {
    isListitem() {
        return this.$slots.headline && this.$slots.headline[0].tag.endsWith('-listitem')
    }
  }
```

**Main problem is** that `$slots` is not reactive

Docs:
*Please note that slots are not reactive. If you need a component to re-render based on changes to data passed to a slot, we suggest considering a different strategy that relies on a reactive instance option, such as `props` or `data`*

So I don't recommend doing this and follow the Vue documentation suggestion to use `props` instead...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use a function to try to get this element by js, something like this:

I am not sure if its will works

```
function checkElement(){
var listitem = document.querySelector("listitem");
  if(listitem) {
   // if exist do something

}
}
```