# Vue.js Limit Type of Child Element

Tags: vue.js

I have been searching but cannot find if this is possible using vue.js. I come from a react background where a similar concept is.

I want to limit the type of child elements that can be nested within `MyCustomComponent` to only allow nested elements of type `MyCustomChild`

**Valid**

```js
<MyCustomComponent>
  <MyCustomChild />
</MyCustomComponent>
```

**Invalid**

```js
<MyCustomComponent>
  <img /> //this should error because img tag is not allowed. Only MyCustomChild tag should be allowed
</MyCustomComponent>
```

Comment: img is a html tag?

Comment: yes... but I want to restrict any tag / component that is not of type `MyCustomChild`

Comment: Why do u need restriction??

Comment: You need to use custom type definitions in typescript for this, i believe. I dont think what you want can he done in javascript. I am learning typescript now, but dont know enough to be able to tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

After some reading I got to the conclusion that we cannot restrict the tags/components accepted in a slot substitution because the way slots are designed. They must accept **any valid template content**.

From the official docs we can read:

> Slot content is not just limited to text. It can be any valid template content.

Source: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#slot-content-and-outlet

Which leads to the answer: We cannot restrict what goes inside of a slot in Vue.js.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments on your post and, how does your template look? I'm guessing you are using slots to nest the components. Maybe an alternative is using named slots and everything not passed in the named slots could be safely ignored.
Since it's up to you to handle the data in your template you could just ignore anything provided in non-namespaced slots.

When using named slots you can safely ignore anything passed to a regular slot if you just ignore it in your template.

I also did some searching and it looks like your question has been answered here:
[Vue - detect component inside slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121792/vue-detect-component-inside-slot#answer-64127356)

Check out the documentation on slots:
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html

Comment: ignoring content not passed to a named slot is NOT intuitive to another developer using the component... the whole point is to have type safety. In React you can explicitly restrict the type of components that are nested. I specifically want the IDE to generate an error if the component is not of a given type.

Comment: an example using React: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65443650/restrict-the-type-of-the-children